# Poisson Bracket for the angular momentum and Runge-Lenz vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, poisson-brackets, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

Given the Runge-Lenz vector

$$\vec{A}=\vec{p}\times\vec{L}-mk\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$$

and the angular momentum

$$\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}$$

We can get

$$\{L^i,A^j\}=\epsilon^{ijk}A^k.$$

I think it is useful to write both as

$A^j=\epsilon^{abc}p_bL_c-mk\frac{r_n}{\sqrt{r^{\alpha}r_{\alpha}}}$
(maybe I'm wrong with the notation)

and

$L^{i}=\epsilon^{ijk}r_{j}p_{k}$

So the Poisson Bracket is expressed by
{$L^{i},A^{j}$}$=${$\epsilon^{ijk}r_{j}p_{k},\epsilon^{abc}p_bL_c-mk\frac{r_n}{\sqrt{r^{\alpha}r_{\alpha}}}$}

and using the properties, I can distribute the components such that

{$L^i,A^j$}={$\epsilon^{ijk}r_{j}p_{k},\epsilon^{abc}p_bL_c$}$-${$\epsilon^{ijk}r_{j}p_{k},mk\frac{r_n}{\sqrt{r^{\alpha}r_{\alpha}}}$}

Doing so, I'm getting for the first bracket

$\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon^{abc}${$r_jp_k,p_bL_c$}=$\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon^{abc}\epsilon^{c\mu\nu}(-r_jp_bp_{\nu}\delta^{k\mu}+p_kr_{\mu}p_{\nu}\delta^{jb}+p_kp_br_{\mu}\delta^{j\nu})$ (by defining $L_c=\epsilon^{c\mu\nu}r_{\mu}p_{\nu}$)

but for the second one, I have

$\epsilon^{ijk}mk${$r_jp_k,\frac{r_n}{\sqrt{r^{\alpha}r_{\alpha}}}$}=$-r_nr_k(r^{\alpha}r_{\alpha})^{-3/2}-(r^{\alpha}r_{\alpha})^{-1/2}\delta^{kn}$

I'd appreciate if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me to do the math!

Comment: What happens to the second term of $A^j$ when $\alpha\neq\beta$?

Comment: I'm using Einstein notation, which implies a summation over the indices. So, if $\alpha\neq\beta$ the term wouldn't be added. So we have, for example in 3 dimensions, 
$mk\frac{r_n}{\sqrt{{r_{1}}^2+{r_2}^2+{r_3}^2}}$

Comment: When $\alpha\neq\beta$, we have that $\frac{r_n}{\sqrt{\delta^{\alpha\beta}r_\alpha r_\beta}}=\frac{r_n}{0}$. You're adding a bunch of infinities to each other.

Comment: And if that's not, in fact, what you're doing, then you need to fix your notation, as the summation over indices occurs at the _term level_, not within the square root.

Comment: I need to express $\frac{1}{\sqrt{{r_1}^2+{r_2}^2+{r_3}^2}}$ in terms of indices, how should I write it then?

Comment: Write $r^\alpha r_\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. But even doing that, at calculate the derivative (from the Poisson bracket) I get one term that it shouldn't appear, which is the one with  $(r^a r_a)^{-3/2}$

Comment: Your expected final expression for the Poisson bracket should have sum  of $A$ components and not that of $L$.